# Dual Monitor Issues

Tags: opensuse, multi-monitor

Two screens

Home screen is on right.

Blank home screen on left.

Mouse will go from left to right and right to left correctly.

Trying to get home screen to the left screen and let the right screen be the blank home screen.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but: The tool you are looking for is called `xrandr`. Run it in the terminal and it will list the monitors, resolution and output (e.g. VGA, DVI). Perhaps simplifying the question would help.

Comment: I updated my question. Hopefully it's a little bit more clear and to the point. I'm basically trying to move the GUI interface to the left screen and let the right screen be the empty home screen.

Comment: @Sebastian is correct. You're problem can be solved using `xrandr`. Read its manpage.

Comment: That was my plan but I thought I'd ask before I dove in with this as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not yet specify whether you're using KDE, Gnome or another window manger. It is likely that they provide an option for this.

Under the hood, these tools are likely to use `xrandr`. If you do not find an option, please post the terminal output of running `xrandr --query`, and I can show you how to use the `--primary` and `--noprimary` option. Here is an example, where `DVI-I-0` is the left primary screen and `DVI-I-1` is the right slave screen:

```
xrandr --output DVI-I-0 --auto --primary --output DVI-I-1 --auto --right-of DVI-I-0
```

You could also try to change the above line to your needs (e.g. `DVI-I-1` may be called `VGA-0` in your case, depending on the cable you use). `xrandr -q` will list this.

Comment: As soon as I get a chance to work on that in the lab on Wednesday I'll see if I can grab some screen shots if I cannot get it to work. I'm pretty certain we switched the screens digital input splinter cable just to get the output backwards and still had the display reversed. It's certainly been odd!

Comment: So I found a GUI way to fix the issue buuuut I was surprised that after changing the cables the numbering assignments stuck. However did a fresh install with both monitors plugged in this time and bam all was good. I found that really weird, I'm wondering if the monitors didn't get remembered somehow and even after the physically moving plug change they don't have some sort of id assigned to them? Anyway thank you for the answer and effort!